# Failed to Parse POM in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am getting the following error when I attempt to execute a maven project using Jenkins.

I keep getting compilation errors all the time. The tests don't run either in Eclipse as Maven nor in Jenkins. I have updated my Jenkins compiler plugin as well.

I know this question has been asked couple of times. I have tried their suggestions and it still did not work. Please advise. Thanks.

```html
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project daily-installer: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[JENKINS] Archiving /nvme/eclipse-workspace/Sample/story-master/pom.xml to com.yellowfin.installer/daily-installer/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/daily-installer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
/nvme/eclipse-workspace/Sample/story-master/pom.xml is not inside /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RegressionStory/nvme/eclipse-workspace/Sample/story-master/; will archive in a separate pass
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RegressionStory/nvme/eclipse-workspace/Sample/story-master/pom.xml
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
 at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
 at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
 at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
 at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
 at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
 at hudson.FilePath.read(FilePath.java:1973)
 at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.properties.PomPropertiesFinder.findProperties(PomPropertiesFinder.java:50)
 at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoExtractor.extract(MavenInfoExtractor.java:58)
 at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoEnvironment.tearDown(MavenInfoEnvironment.java:42)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:908)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1815)
 at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

Here is my folder structure in eclipse  [image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your project folder structure and jenkinsfile ( where you read pom file) i believe there is a location mismatch in jenkinsfile.

Comment: Please see the folder structure above

Comment: Please give pom.xml instead of 
/nvme/eclipse-workspace/Sample/story-master/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

When you checkout the sources, the location of pom.xml will be relative to the project folder. The pom.xml is in root of your project. So,
Please give `pom.xml` instead of

```
/nvme/eclipse-workspace/Sample/story-master/pom.xml
```

Let me know if it doesnt work for you.

Comment: please share the updated error - console log. Well fix it

Comment: Please see the screenshot above

Comment: how many poms are there in the project? and whats the project name? (story-master or  RegressionStory)? Do you have it in github or something so that I can take a look at it?

Comment: There is only one POM. The project name is story-master and RegressionStory is name of the Jenkins job. I don't have it in github. I will need to upload it

Comment: are these in server? or in your personal laptop something? How is the source code cloned to jenkins workspace?? Where do you maintain your source code?

Comment: yes they are in my jenkins server. We have our own internal gitlab account through which I have downloaded the source code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181595/discussion-between-anand-varkey-philips-and-bob-jones).